# Maxmind list all cities in a state

Tags: javascript, node.js, geoip, maxmind

I am using maxmind node module to interact with the maxmind database. What I am trying to achieve is to get a list of all cities under specific state/country. 
The code is as follow.

```
var maxmind = require('maxmind');
maxmind.open('/path/to/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', (err, cityLookup) => {
   var city = cityLookup.get('66.6.44.4');
});
```

I dont think there is an option of listing all cities under state name.or search database via state/country name. 
Is there an alternative option ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. The database is designed to do lookups by IP address. I would suggest using the CSV files that MaxMind provides if you need to access the data in some other way.